# Calculating elevation profile along line from a DEM?

Tags: raster, dem, open-source-gis, elevation, profile

Given a DEM (Digital Elevation Model) and a line (x1,y1) --> (x2,y2) (paired coordinates (x,y)), how can one calculate the elevation profile or cross-section projected on that line?

I am looking for an open source code that I can use in my project or pseudo-code that I can use as a guide.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The GRASS command `r.profile` performs this ([documentation](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/html65_user/r.profile.html), [source](http://trac.osgeo.org/grass/browser/grass/trunk/raster/r.profile)) and should provide a good basis for implementing a cross section, and is available under the GPL.

Answer (score 12):

Maybe [QGIS "Profile" plugin](http://bwj.aster.net.pl/qgis/index.html#profile) [source code](http://spatialserver.net/pyqgis_1.0/contributed/profiletool.zip) can be a start.

[image]

Comment: This would be nice thing to have built into QGIS.  Maybe under the raster menu.  Also have multiple lines the GRASS example would be cool.

Answer (score 5):

You can go much further by combining DEM and raster colors, using GRASS with R. See:

- [Raster profile along arbitrary line segments](http://casoilresource.lawr.ucdavis.edu/drupal/node/375), or
- [http://www.portailsig.org/content/grass-gis-et-r-superposition-des-couleurs-d-un-raster-quelconque-sur-un-profil-topographique](https://portailsig.org/content/grass-gis-et-r-superposition-des-couleurs-d-un-raster-quelconque-sur-un-profil-topographique.html) and,
- with Python ([Python: utilisation des couches vectorielles et matricielles dans une perspective géologique, sans logiciel SIG](https://portailsig.org/content/python-utilisation-des-couches-vectorielles-et-matricielles-dans-une-perspective-geologique-.html); in French, but the scripts are universal).

See some examples below:

With elevation colors (GRASS GIS and R):

[image]

With colors of a Geological Map (Python with GRASS raster):

[image]

And using the Python script in the Python console of QGIS:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here screenshots for GRASS: [image] [image]

Comment: Are these pictures derived from the tool specified in scw's answer (r.profile), or are they from another tool (a GUI tool, for example)? Perhaps the answer could be improved if you specify the name of the tool, some reference for its documentation and where it can be accessed within the software.