# Getting flood depth grid values for road segments?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, road, esri-grid-format, flood, depth

I have a 2 features, the first contains values for flood depth (Raster, GRID). the other is a road network (vector, polyline) that has been clipped to the boundary of the depth grid. I am racking my brain trying to figure out how to get the maximum flood depth for each road segment where it crosses the Flood Depth GRID and I am unable to come up with a method to achieve this. I am using ArcGIS 10.2 Basic, but do have access to an advanced license if necessary.

[image: Screen capture of road segment and depth grid]

Comment: Does [this post](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/how-to-calculate-an-elevation-profile-for-a-polyline-in-arcgis-10-with-spatial-a) answer your question? You'll need access to 3D Analyst.

Comment: Place points at regular interval <= cell size. Make sure points receive lineID. Use Extract values to points (Spatial Analyst) to sample your raster. Apply field statistics on derived depths using lineID as case field. Alternatively create small buffer around lines and do zonal statistics. Both assumes you have Spatial Analyst. If not there are other ways around

Comment: @FelixIP, is there a simple way to automate placing points at regular intervals along a line? I have several hundred segments in my AOI an would prefer not to have to place them manually.

Comment: I have a script tool, shall I post it?

Comment: @FelixIP, That would be wonderful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked post will give you your answer... But those profile graphs are pretty useless graphics. The point thing will work, but might miss the actual maximum or you might needlessly create far too many points. I think you could avoid it all by using the Add Surface Information tool from the 3D Analyst toolbox and asking for Z_MAX.
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q900000016000000

Comment: Did exactly what I needed it to do. Didn't know that that tool even existed, thanks.