# Is there a tool in GIS to find the surface of a profile section in a DEM?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, dem, geometry, elevation

For example I have a DEM of river bed over which we made several profiles – eg sketch: http://prntscr.com/cqwile 
Now in cross section, it will look like this http://prntscr.com/cqwx59 .

Is there a way in GIS to find the surface of the green area by adding the DEM and a profile line from which it should be measured?

Or maybe set a Plane Height from which to start.

Comment: Did you see http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/calculating-elevation-profile-for-a-polyline-in-arcgis-10 or find http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/fundamentals-of-creating-profile-graphs.htm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such tool, I decided to make one.

In order to test it, I created 4 copies of the same polyline, and used DEM available and interpolate shape tool to convert them into 3D lines.

[image: INPUT]

SCRIPT:

```
import arcpy
from math import hypot
inLines = r"C:\FELIX_DATA\SCRARCH\line3d.shp"

g=arcpy.Geometry()
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(inLines,("Shape@","WL","Channels","SectArea")) as cursor:
  for shp,wl,channels,sArea in cursor:
    part=shp.getPart(0); array=arcpy.Array();L=0
    for i,p in enumerate(part):
      if i==0:p1=p
      else:
        p2=p
        L+=hypot(p1.X-p2.X,p1.Y-p2.Y)
        p1=p
      array.add(arcpy.Point(L,p.Z))
    section=arcpy.Polyline(array)
    LeftPoint=arcpy.Point(0,wl)
    RightPoint=arcpy.Point(L,wl)
    horizontal=arcpy.Polyline(arcpy.Array([LeftPoint,RightPoint]))
    G=arcpy.FeatureToPolygon_management([section,horizontal],g)
    channels=0;sArea=0
    for pgon in G:
      extent=pgon.extent
      if 0.5*(extent.YMax+extent.YMin)>=wl: continue
      channels+=1;sArea+=pgon.area
    arcpy.AddMessage(channels)
    cursor.updateRow((shp,wl,channels,sArea))
```

OUTPUT:

[image: OUTPUT]

Note:

I used in memory geometries as inputs to mighty polygon constructing tool. I think this is very GIS solution to the task. Script will work on v.1.0 and later, not on 9.3.

Comment: That looks awesome! One question, so for a single profile, i need several copies? or in the attribute table of the line there are several depths?

Comment: Several copies of the same line. If it works for you mark as solves please

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only built-in functionality related to the profile section in ArcGIS Desktop is located in 3D Analyst toolbar via **Profile Graph**. You can read from [the respective help page](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/3d-analyst/fundamentals-of-creating-profile-graphs.htm) how to do this. This help page states that

> you can create profiles on either a raster, triangulated irregular
>   network (TIN), or terrain dataset surface.

I used this tool in version 10.3, and remember that it draws you a functional profile (as expected) but there are a few visualisation related limitations which make it hard to produce pleasing graphics.

Answer (score -1):

We use Global Mapper for applications like this.  They have a profile tool that allows you to at this in detail including cut and fill volumes.

Comment: could you tell me which tool that is?