# Transfering height information from DEM to line feature to use in profile with ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: dem, arcgis-pro

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.4.

I want to make a height profile of a line segment. The line has no height information, so I want to transfer height information to the line from a dem.

How can this be done?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating elevation profile for a polyline in ArcGIS 10?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25109/calculating-elevation-profile-for-a-polyline-in-arcgis-10)

Comment: That "duplicate" does not transfer values from raster to line.

Comment: Have you tried the [Update Feature Z](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/3d-analyst/update-feature-z.htm#) tool?

Comment: Install QGIS and `Drape`