# Orthogonal Height Profile along line (sextante -> v.segment, r.profile?)

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation, sextante-qgis-plugin, profile

While trying to find a way to find "valleys/ridges" within a DEM, I'd
like to know if there are tools, plugins or "methods" known or
available to automatically generate height profiles along a given
path.

Or maybe a tool that (allows to) calculates the height profile
(UNIX preferred, no Windows at all) at a certain position, takin
coords and azimut as input?

**--- / edit 19.12. --- /**

Even though I'm yet not used to sextante and GRASS at all, I've searched and read a lot. Shouldn't it be possible to solve above discribed problem by using the sextante modeller?

If there is a single line within a line-shape plus a raster elevation map...

Shouldnt it be possible to...

1. Step: generate points using *v.segment* with direction (within line) as attributes for the resulting points **P**.
2. Step: generate 2 new points for every **P** within a fixed given distance, which mark the start and end of an orthogonal line (angle from "directon" at step-1), where **P** is the middle resp. point of intersection.
3. Step: calculate profile of this orthogonal using *r.profile*
4. Step: write/append elevation profile to a CSV with <del>lat/lon/height</del> **x/y/elev**, so that it can be further processed or simply beeing 3D illustrated via Speadsheet, gnuplot,..

The lan/lot is delete cause I didnt point out I would like to have it "straightned". Otherwise I could simply wrap the area from the DEM.

An please - as mentioned - I'm new to GRASS and even less when it comes to the modeller :-/   It's not too long ago I started using the sextante toolbox to improove the possibilities within QGIS.

Below show my two rasters examples. First one is straight ASTER elevation data overlayed by a rugh drawn line from a geological map, respresenting a tectonic fault.

Second on is the terrain convergence index (tci) of the DEM, where I get the impression that I can see this line.

[image: ASTER elevation data]

[image: terrain convergence index]

Answer (score 2):

Please look for existing answers prior to asking a question. You can find all the answers and tools for QGIS and GRASS in this existing [thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/code-to-calculate-elevation-profile-along-line-from-a-dem?rq=1)

EDIT:
But still need a Height Profile? Google Earth maybe [has something](http://support.google.com/earth/bin/answer.py?answer=181393) like this and is also available for Unix/Windows and co.

Comment: I ment something like a tool, which not only genrates a point layer from given lines, but far mor somethin that generates 90°/rectangular line-profiles based on a given line.

Example:
Give a path through a valley and the result will be a set of profiles at coord xy with azimuth z, producing a new layer with a 90° vector and elevation attribute.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't point out at all that I mean the profile 90° to the path!