# How to extract elevation data from DEM along a polyline

Tags: qgis, dem, elevation

I've been trying to use qGIS to extract and save as an attribute the data elevation along a line, knowing that something similar is available in ArcGIS using the Spatial Analysis tool.  So far, though, I've been unable to find the right tools in qGIS.

I imagine this will involve two separate steps: first creating a point layer at even intervals along a line, and then extracting the elevation of each point.  I'll keep plugging away at the problem, but if anyone had any pointers, all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: anything different from this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/1946/code-to-calculate-elevation-profile-along-line-from-a-dem?rq=1 ?

Comment: Somehow I missed that post.  Looks like r.Profile is the tool I need.  Thanks for that.